# How do you create a DateTime object with its last day of the month?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've been searching myself but couldn't find anything. Is there any way to create a Datetime with the last day of its month? I know you can get the last day of a specific month by doing:

```
$a_date = "2009-11-23";
date("Y-m-t", strtotime($a_date));
```

But is it possible or is there any way to create a DateTime object like this?

```
$date = new DateTime("2009-11-t 00:00:00");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
$date = new DateTime('2009-11-23');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant (declaring a DateTime with its last day already set) but most likely the easiest solution. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can create a function 
`function give_last_month_day($date) {
        $date = new DateTime($date);
        $date->modify('last day of this month');
        return $date;
    }
`
Date is a string